# how can only package up dockerfile+jar like `distTar` not build image

Tags: spring, gradle, docker, spring-boot

how can only package up `dockerfile+jar` like `distTar` not build image

https://github.com/Transmode/gradle-docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
distDocker {
  dryRun = true
}
```